# How to remove one word from the url while redirect from non-www to www in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, server

The actual issue is that the site is redirecting to http://www.example.com/public/other-url.

I need to remove

> public

word from the url to serve it like http://www.example.com/other-url

I am using following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this might work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/public/other-url(.*)$
RewriteRule ^public/other-url(.*)$ /other-url$1 [R=301,L]
```